# Postgres Select Distinct Starts with

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where one of the columns contains URL.
I want to see all the hosts that are registered, but Those hosts have different params over.
(http://myUrl/deviceId/[RandomId])

I want to get all those URLs, but I don't really care about the params that are sent over.

Let's say I have 100,000 records

50,000 are http://myUrl1/deviceId/[RandomId]

40,000 are http://myOtherUrl/OtherParam/[Param]

10,000 are http://AnythingElse

Any way to get only 3 records out of a query? (1 for each different host?)

Comment: provide a syntax of your query to solve your issues

Comment: bring more clarity to your question

Comment: Use string manipulation to cut away the useless parts, then use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `Select distinct  left(urlcol, strpos(substr(urlcol,8),'/')+6)` , this or minor changes to this will help you.

Comment: Anand - that worked perfectly